# graphviz autofit TD width in html label

Tags: html, label, width, graphviz

With the following `dot`

```
digraph structs {
node [shape=plaintext]
struct1 [label=<
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <TABLE  border="1">
                <TR>
                    <TD align="left">one</TD>
                    <TD align="left">long text here</TD>
                    <TD align="left">c</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <TABLE  border="1">
                <TR>
                    <TD align="left">very long text present here</TD>
                    <TD align="left">colb</TD>
                    <TD align="left">colc</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
>];
}
```

Graphviz yields the image below (my notes with red):

[image]

Now, if I take the table HTML from above and render it in the browser, I get what I would also expect from Graphviz:

[image]

Question: how can i get Graphviz to render the table same as the browser does (no extra-space inside the columns, but instead have it after the last column) ?

If it's not possible, how do I input the node label so that I get the same result as the browser returns?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a one-time problem or do you need a generic (repeatable) solution?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - repeatable solution please. So it’s not as easy as adding somewhere a parameter I missed in the docs…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible workarounds:

```
digraph structs {
node [shape=plaintext]
struct1 [label=<
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <TABLE border="0" width="1" fixedsize="true" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellsborder="0" CELLSPACING="0">
                <TR>
                    <TD align="left">
            <TABLE  border="1" >
                <TR>
                    <TD align="left">one</TD>
                    <TD align="left">long text here</TD>
                    <TD align="left">c</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <TABLE  border="1">
                <TR>
                    <TD align="left">very long text present here</TD>
                    <TD align="left">colb</TD>
                    <TD align="left">colc</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
>];
}
```

rendered on: http://viz-js.com/

[image]